# How can React access Hooks functions' local variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Below is a simple hook

```
function App() {
  let [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  return <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>{counter}</button>;
}
```

My understanding on how react works is:

React will call `App()` to get a React element as:

```
let element = App();
```

and the element can be rendered on the browser, fair enough.

Now I click the button to increment the `counter`, here is what I don't understand:

we all know a fucntion's local variables (counter, setCounter) get destoryed/discarded when the function finishes the execution and get popped out from the stack, so how can `setCounter` and `counter` can be accessed again in the callback if those two variables are no longer available?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of how React works is mostly correct, but there's a bit more going on behind the scenes.

When you call `App()`, it returns a React element, but it doesn't directly render the element on the browser. Instead, React takes that element and creates a virtual representation of the DOM (Virtual DOM) based on it. This virtual representation is a lightweight copy of the actual DOM tree that React uses to efficiently compute the changes that need to be made.

Now, let's focus on the useState hook in your example. When the component function `App()` is called, React initializes the `counter` state variable to 0 and the `setCounter` function that allows updating the state. These variables are not just regular local variables like you would have in a normal function. Instead, they are part of what we call a "closure."

A closure is a function along with its lexical environment, which consists of any variables that were in scope when the function was defined. In other words, the function keeps access to the variables that were available in the scope where it was defined, even if that scope has finished executing and the local variables would usually be discarded.

So when the `onClick` callback is triggered, it is able to access the `setCounter` function because it is part of the closure of the `App()` function. The `setCounter` function, in turn, has access to the `counter` variable, which it updates when invoked with a new value.

In simple terms, you can think of it this way: The `App()` function creates a closure that captures the `counter` state variable and the `setCounter` function. When the button is clicked and the callback is executed, it's able to access the `setCounter` function, which, in turn, can access and update the `counter` variable, thanks to the closure mechanism.

So, even though the local variables of the `App()` function would usually be destroyed after the function finishes executing, React's closure mechanism ensures that the state and updater functions are preserved and accessible when needed. This allows React to maintain and manage stateful data in functional components effectively.

Answer (score 1):

When the `App()` function is initially called, the `useState(0)` call sets up a closure. A closure allows a function to remember the variables in its scope at the time it was created. In this case, it remembers the counter and `setCounter` variables even after the `App()` function finishes executing.

When you click the button and trigger the onClick event, the callback function `() => setCounter(counter + 1)` is executed. Despite the fact that the `App()` function has already completed, the callback function retains access to the `counter` and `setCounter` variables through the closure.

Here's a link for your reference,
[Closures in javascript](https://dev.to/mattdclarke/what-is-a-closure-example-use-cases-in-javascript-and-react-2e6j)

One suggestion is try not to use state in the child component and instead pass the state from parent to child and update the parent component state from child just like in the example from the reference

Comment: but if the local variables `counter, setCounter` has been destroyed after `App() ` finishes, how can the callback access them again? unless javascript create a dummy object/class like C#'s compiler to be able to use them?

Comment: In the context of regular JavaScript functions, local variables are typically destroyed after the function finishes executing. However, in the case of React functional components, things work a bit differently.

After the initial execution, React maintains the state values internally and takes care of updating them as needed. When the component is re-rendered (due to state changes, props updates, or other reasons), React retains the current state and any changes to it.

Comment: So, the variables counter and `setCounter` themselves are not destroyed or discarded after the `App()` function finishes executing. They are preserved by React behind the scenes and accessible during the lifecycle of the component